# Get command hangs using VS 2012 and TFS 2008 (TFS error TF400307)

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Today, all of a sudden, I found out I am not able to succesfully complete any type of get command on our TFS. All the time the process just hangs at some point, progress bar and status message with currently processed file staying the same forever, no errors thrown. This happens on a different file every time, sooner or later into the process with both the IDE and the command line utility.

I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2012 with TFS 2008.

I've never had a similar problem before and yesterday everything worked fine. I'm not aware of any configuration changes since then and I am the only one in the company experiencing the problem.

I don't suppose there is a direct answer to why this happens, but could someone provide any pointers on how to go about debugging and solving such issue?

So far I've tried various ways of running the get command - latest version, specific version, map + get latest, both inside VS IDE and via command line. Also many other TFS commands seem to be working well.

**Edit:**

After some trial and error, leaving the process going for an hour or so, I finally stumbled upon the error messages in the source control output window. These weren't visible initially, because when the process hanged, it made the whole IDE unresponsive. The messages are all the same:

> [file path]: TF400307: The download operation timed out after waiting 599 seconds for a response from the server.

Comment: Do you happen to have AVG or another antivirus installed?

Comment: We use ESET NOD32 Antivirus company wide and for a long time, so I don't think this is an issue. As I said, I don't know about any OS or software configuration change since it was working yesterday.

Comment: We are using a third one: Symantec Endpoint Protection. I have to try the technique which marked as the answer.

Comment: We get the issue with a Diff, rather than a Get Latest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same issue with TFS where it would hang and become unresponsive.

I found a solution to this by updating the tf.exe.config or devenv.exe.config file with the following configuration values:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="1000"/>
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

I set the limit to 1000 on my side, as I carefully watched the value in Resource Monitor, though truthfully I never got higher than 600 concurrent connections.

Comment: Stumbled on the issue once again when changing the TFS mappings. I added this to my Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config and it seems to be working fine. Definitely better solution than using the older TFS, I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 3):

So what happens is that TFS client in VS 2012 has a bug in it that causes it to start timeouting on all the files after some time into the process when running a get command for a *bigger* number of files.

As mentioned in the MS Connect ticket below, the workaround for now is to use the older TFS client to run the timeouting commands. I succesfully used the VS 2010 command line TFS client to do the get on the project.

- [Microsoft Connect - Visual Studio: Get latest version fails with timeout](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748576/get-latest-version-fails-with-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue getting latest version with VS 2012 from TFS 2008. Using the debugger and Fiddler tool I was able to catch the moment VS hangs. Looks like something is wrong when VS 2012 recieves some compressed TFS server HTTP responses, it can't decompress them and hangs. After I turned off compression for TFS HTTP traffic VS hangs no more. Hope it helps someone else.

To turn off TFS compression create registry value and restart VS:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\RequestSettings 
EnableCompression(REG_SZ)=”false”

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue. Changing Workspace worked for me i.e. I removed the old workspace and created a new one where I again mapped the required projects and It worked like a charm!.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, you are very patient! I got also a "TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from the server xyz. Technical information (for administrator): The operation timed out" error from Source Control Explorer after I cancelled the Get latest process and waited for ages.
It is maybe about not the number of files, but the amount of data? It hangs to me after approx ~2GB data transferred, which is exactly when a 32bit signed integer overflows, but that's just a suspicion.
Ticket: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776506/source-control-explorer-getlatest-hangs-after-certain-amount-of-data-transferred-might-be-integer-overflow#tabs

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when I called the CreateWorkspace method with new WorkFolders mappings as parameter it started pulling down all the files (mapped to $/) to local which would explain the long processing time - changed to CreateWorkspace with null for WorkFolders than added next step seemed to do the trick